# Avoid symbolic evaluation with NSolve and compiled function

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, compile

**Problem**

I have a compiled function that I want to use in an equation given to NSolve. I can get the code to run, but it first produces warning messages that result from NSolve trying to evaluate the function with symbolic arguments. I want to prevent that attempt from happening.

To demonstrate the problem and avoid unrelated details of my application, I've created a compiled version of the `Beta` function.

```
Clear[myBetaV1];
myBetaV1 = Compile[{{alpha, _Real}, {beta, _Real}},
   Exp[LogGamma[alpha] + LogGamma[beta] - LogGamma[alpha + beta]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Now suppose I want to solve the equation

```
NSolve[Beta[5, 3] == myBetaV1[a, 3], a, Reals]
(*CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument a at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.
NSolve::fexp: Warning: NSolve used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the solution set might have been altered.
{{a -> 5.}}*)
```

The first message, about a machine-size real number, happens because the symbol `a` in `myBetaV1[a,3]` is not a machine-size real number.

**Attempted solutions**

**1)** Include `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` as an option given to NSolve

```
NSolve[Beta[5, 3] == myBetaV1[a, 3], a, Reals, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
(*CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument a at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.
NSolve::fexp: Warning: NSolve used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the solution set might have been altered.
{{a -> 5.}}*)
```

That option doesn't appear to change anything.

**2)** Use `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}` as an option when creating the compiled function, and try in combination with attempt 1.

```
Clear[myBetaV2];
myBetaV2 = Compile[{{alpha, _Real}, {beta, _Real}},
   Exp[LogGamma[alpha] + LogGamma[beta] - LogGamma[alpha + beta]],
   RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False},
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];

NSolve[Beta[5, 3] == myBetaV2[a, 3], a, Reals]
(*NSolve[1/105 == CompiledFunction[][a, 3], a, Reals]*)

NSolve[Beta[5, 3] == myBetaV2[a, 3], a, Reals, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
(*NSolve[1/105 == CompiledFunction[][a, 3],a, Reals, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]*)
```

Now NSolve doesn't even find the solution with warning messages.

**3)** Wrap the compiled function in a rule with `NumericQ` pattern tests to ensure it is called with numeric arguments.

```
Clear[myBetaV3];
myBetaV3[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] = myBetaV2[a, b];

NSolve[Beta[5, 3] == myBetaV3[a, 3], a, Reals]
(*NSolve[1/105 == myBetaV3[a, 3], a, Reals]*)

NSolve[Beta[5, 3] == myBetaV3[a, 3], a, Reals, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
(*NSolve[1/105 == myBetaV3[a, 3], a, Reals, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]*)
```

This didn't work either.

**Question**

How do I use a compiled function within an equation given to NSolve and avoid any attempts to evaluate the function symbolically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From its documentation, "NSolve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations."  I find that `FindRoot` does not exhibit the behaviour you wish to suppress.  (Guessing: perhaps `NSolve` attempts to get a symbolic gradient, or some other measure of sensitivity, which `FindRoot` does not.)  Mix in your `NumericQ` test and I think you have what you want.

```
Clear[myBetaV1];
myBetaV1 = 
    Compile[{{alpha, _Real}, {beta, _Real}}, 
        Exp[LogGamma[alpha] + LogGamma[beta] - LogGamma[alpha + beta]], 
        CompilationTarget -> "C"];

FindRoot[Beta[5, 3] == myBetaV1[a, 3], {a, 5}]
(* CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument a at position 1 should be a machine-size real number. >>  *)
(* {a -> 5.} *)

myBetaV3[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := myBetaV1[a, b];

FindRoot[Beta[5, 3] == myBetaV3[a, 3], {a, 5}]
(* {a -> 5.} *)
```

Note that I've added the given value of the first argument to `Beta` as a starting place for `FindRoot`.  I don't trust me to remember to change that starting point every time, so

```
findAlpha[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
    FindRoot[Beta[a, b] == myBetaV3[α, b], {α, a}]

findAlpha[5, 3]
(* {a -> 5.} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for directing me to `FindRoot`. I also discovered that removing the restriction to `Reals` resolves the problem for `NSolve` with `myBetaV3` in my example.