# Compile and NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, compile

Consider the following numerical problem. One deals with transcendental complicated function `f` that depends on several parameters and three variables, say `x`, `y` and `z`. One wants to find roots of the equation `f[x,y,z]==0` for a given values `x1` and `y1` (i.e. solve `f[x,y,z]` with respect to `z` for known values `x` and `y`. Important moment that it is possible to have more thatn one root of `f[x,y,z]==0` for `x1` and `y1`.

Then, for a given lists `{x}` and `{y}`, one solves equation at each point on grid `(x,y)` and obtain the list `z`. It can be realized as follows (schematically!):

```
roots = z/.NDSolve[f[#1,#2,z]==0 && g[#1,#2]<=z<=h[#1,#2]]&;
zvalues = ParallelTable[root[X,Y], ... ]
```

I write down `ParallelTable` because I am not sure that the function `roots` is listable, i.e. I am not sure that `Map` or `MapThread` works.

Then, one notices that this procedure is quite long. The first guess is to try use `Compile`.

So, the following questions appear:

1. Is it possible to find numerically all roots of equation on a given interval by a method, that can be used in `Compile`?
2. Or, is it possible to use `NSolve` in `Compile`?

I have a vague feeling that [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152249/avoid-symbolic-evaluation-with-nsolve-and-compiled-function) question is relevant.
With help of kind people, I obtain the following code snippet:

```
NewtonMethodCompiled::usage = 
"NewtonMethodCompiled[function][x0]. \n\
NewtonMethodCompiled[function, delta, epsilon][x0]. \n\
NewtonMethodCompiled[function, \"Delta\" -> delta, \"Epsilon\" -> epsilon][x0]. "; 

Options[NewtonMethodCompiled] = {"Delta" -> 0.0001, "Epsilon" -> 0.0001}; 

NewtonMethodCompiled[f_Function, OptionsPattern[]] := 
NewtonMethodCompiled[f, OptionValue["Delta"], OptionValue["Epsilon"]]; 

NewtonMethodCompiled[f_Function, delta_Real, epsilon_Real] := 
NewtonMethodCompiled[f, delta, epsilon] = 
Compile[{{x0, _Complex}}, 
    Module[{xi, df}, 
        xi = x0; 
        While[epsilon < Abs[f[xi]] < Abs[f[x0]] / epsilon, 
            df = (f[xi + delta/2] - f[xi - delta/2]) / delta;
            xi = xi - f[xi] / df; 
        ]; 
        
        Return[xi] 
    ], 
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
];
```

**It is the realization of compiled Newton method**

Comment: `Compile` can make external calls, so, technically yes, you can use such tools as `NSolve`, `NDSolve`, etc. as long as your code returns a type of expression supported by the WVM (machine numeric/boolean scalars and a arrays). It is possible to wrap `NSolve` in code that returns a numeric array of solutions.  However, functions that don't return supported data types cannot be run solely within the WVM. -- I suppose you've probably seen this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you! My function that contains `NSolve` returns list of reals and naive compilation produces `CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression {0.396782,0.785873} should be a machine-size real number.` . I will check documentation and the mentioned question